# how to submit the form if an ajax response is true?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms

I have a form that have `onsubmit = "return function()"`

```
<form onsubmit="return checkCartExistingInHolding()" action="..." method="post">
    @csrf
    <button id="payment" class="btn btn-success-theme payment-btn mt-5 mb-5" disabled>پرداخت</button>
</form>
```

and the ajax method is :

```
function checkCartExistingInHolding(){
console.log('in func');
var isComplete = $.ajax({
    url: "/cart/checkCartExistInHolding",
    method: "get",
    async: false,
    success: function (response) {
        if(response === true){
            console.log('is true');
            return true;
        }else{
            console.log('is false');
            $('tbody[role="cartlist"]').html("");
            $('tbody[role="cartlist"]').html(response);
            // empty_cart_viewport();
            traverse(document.body);
            setEventListeners();
            return false
        }
    },
});
return isComplete;
}
```

But the form don't get the `false` response from ajax and don't prevent from submission.
also In false ajax don't change the viewport items.
where I did go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that, instead of using the onsubmit event, make your button call your Ajax function directly. And only on success submit your form with: `document.getElementById('myForm').submit()`